# Eclipse Can not access adb.exe

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I Have Problem In Eclipse 
can not access adb.exe
and when accessing adb.exe in

> C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but I'd like to suggest to you to use Android Studio as it provides all the tools and features needs for android development!

Comment: try to run eclipse as administrator

Comment: Probably your SDK is not set properly or its path is not added as an environment variable hence eclipse is not able to detect adb

Comment: Try to run eclipse as an administrator.

Comment: My problem in adb.exe not found in taskmanager